# CSS line-height invert proportionally to the font-size

Tags: css, sass

I am using the css `line-height` propriety to position the `:before`text of the `li` element  vertically in the middle of it's border as you can see in the snippet. My problem is that I want it to stay at the middle if the font size changed (for example if  the user used the zoom text only functionality of the firefox browser). I thought of using `line-height: calc(1 / 2em)` but this wouldn't work since the `/` operator accepts only a number at the right side. here is my code

```css
li {
     list-style-type: none;
     width: 20%;
     float: left;
     font-size: 10px;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color: purple;
}
li:before {
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     border: 4px solid purple;
     content: counter(step);
     counter-increment: step;
     line-height: 40px;
     font-size: 15px;
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
     border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li> element</li>
<li> element</li>
<li> element</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: _“I thought of using line-height: calc(1 / 2em) but this wouldn't work since the / operator accepts only a number at the right side”_ - well it would not even make sense to begin with, because only `em` is a valid length unit, 1/em is not ...

Comment: Apart from that, I don’t see what ::after is even doing here, it doesn’t seem to achieve anything in your example.

Comment: Anyway, there are lots of ways to center stuff in CSS, and line-height isn’t a particularly good one to begin with. So, do some research please.

Comment: @CBroe yes you are right I made a mistake while posting the question the after is for something else not related to the question. I corrected the question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `flexbox` to align items inside your `li` which I think is a better solution than `line-height`

Try :

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

in your `li:before` and remove the `line-height`. I think you will get the desired result.

Hope this helps